# Unable to add toolbar in Python addin wizard

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, toolbar

I am trying to create a customized tool in an ArcPy script.

For that I want to add a tool in a toolbar in the Python addin wizard. I have downloaded the Python addin wizard and am trying to add a toolbar in the Add-in contents tab.

How do I add a tool in a toolbar in the Python Addin Wizard.

Answer (score 2):

The help page [Creating an add-in toolbar](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/creating-an-add-in-toolbar.htm) says:

> Once you have entered the required project settings, click on the
>   **Add-In Contents** tab. To create a new toolbar, right-click on **TOOLBARS**
>   and click New Toolbar.

The help page [Creating a Python add-in tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/creating-an-add-in-tool.htm) says:

> This topic guides you through the process of creating a tool on a new
>   toolbar using the **Python Add-In Wizard**

so these pages would seem to be the best place to start.

If you get stuck then describe in detail which of those instructions seem to work and precisely where you get stuck.